# Linq to Entities : How to filter master table rows based on child rows properties

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a master table `Person` and a detail table `Events`

I need to filter master table rows based on child row property `SomeId`.

Could anyone please show me how to do it ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works!

```
var q = from p in db.Persons
        join ev in db.Events on p.Id equals ev.PersonId
        where ev.SomeId == 4
        select p;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = db.Events.Where(p=>p.SomeId == 4).Select(p=>p.Person).Distinct();
```